# JavaFX How to Vertically Align CheckBox in an HBox in a GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

First, code that generates a UI that illustrates the problem:

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage window) throws Exception {
        // Create a VBox to hold the table and button
        final GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setHgap(5);
        root.setVgap(5);

        // Add a combo-box to the first row
        final ComboBox<String> dropdown1 = new ComboBox<>();
        dropdown1.getItems().add("Option 1");
        dropdown1.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        root.add(dropdown1, 0, 0);

        // Add a checkbox to the first row
        final CheckBox checkbox1 = new CheckBox("CB Text 1");
        root.add(checkbox1, 1, 0);

        // Add a combo-box to the second row
        final ComboBox<String> dropdown2 = new ComboBox<>();
        dropdown2.getItems().add("Option 2");
        dropdown2.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        root.add(dropdown2, 0, 1);

        // Add a checkbox, wrapped in an HBox, to the second row
        final CheckBox checkbox2 = new CheckBox("CB Text 2");
        final HBox hbox = new HBox(checkbox2);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        root.add(hbox, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setValignment(hbox, VPos.BASELINE);

        // Show the JavaFX window
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

The above code generates the following UI (Java 8u102 Windows x64):

[image: Example Application]

As shown in the image, the vertical alignment of the `CheckBox` in the second row is misaligned with the `ComboBox`.  I expect everything to be aligned on the text baseline.  How can I get the second row in the `GridPane` to match the alignment of the first row, without removing the `HBox`?

Comment: You can for example use: `hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);` and `checkbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the code that populates the offending cell to be the following:

```
// Add a checkbox, wrapped in an HBox, to the second row
final CheckBox checkbox2 = new CheckBox("CB Text 2");
final HBox hbox = new HBox(checkbox2);
hbox.setFillHeight(true);          // Added this
hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);// Changed the alignment to center-left
root.add(hbox, 1, 1);
//GridPane.setValignment(hbox, VPos.BASELINE); This is unnecessary
```

This code will force the `HBox` to be the same height as the row, then vertically center the `CheckBox` within it.